# Scrollbars in JScrollPane don't refresh

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, preferredsize

I have a JPanel in a JScrollPane. When JPanel changes (in my case, I draw an image inside), the scroll bars are not refreshing accordingly. I need to move them sligthly or resize the whole frame and then everything is fine. How to force JScrollPane to show correct scroll bars (ie. after loading the picture)?

Comment: For better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Make sure that the preferred size of the viewport view is updated (either by appropriate override or with appropriate LayoutManager) and then call `revalidate()` on the viewport view.

Answer (score 3):

You should include these methods when you want to modify the JScrollPane according to some changes:

```
JScrollPane.setViewportView(this);  
JScrollPane.revalidate();  
JScrollPane.repaint();
```

Comment: `JScrollPane.setViewportView(this);` is enough. The next two lines are needless because the viewport will call them automatically for you.